# Pyplot set_xticks doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to set the x tick density by specifying how many ticks to skip each time. For example, if the x axis is labelled by 100 consecutive dates, and I want to skip every 10 dates, then I will do something like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = pd.period_range("20060101", periods=100).strftime("%Y%m%d")
y = np.random.randn(100)
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(ts, y)
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[::10])
plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

However the output is out of place. Pyplot only picks the first few ticks and place them all in the wrong positions, although the spacing is correct:

[image]

What can I do to get the desired output? Namely the ticks should be instead:

```
['20060101' '20060111' '20060121' '20060131' '20060210' '20060220'
 '20060302' '20060312' '20060322' '20060401']
```

@klim's answer seems to put the correct marks on the axis, but the labels still won't show. An example where the date axis is correctly marked yet without labels:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set xticklabels also. Like this.

```
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xticklabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[::10])
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels[::10], rotation=90)
```

---

Forget the above, which doesn't work.

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = pd.period_range("20060101", periods=100).strftime("%Y%m%d")
x = np.arange(len(ts))
y = np.random.randn(100)
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticks(x[::10])
ax.set_xticklabels(ts[::10], rotation="vertical")

plt.show()
```

This works on my machine.

Comment: In this case it seems the ticks are correctly returned (because the grid lines are correctly spaced), but the labels won't show.

Comment: Ok it works now. Thanks! Somehow there was a glitch just now and I don't know why

Comment: Sorry there is yet another glitch... the scale on the x-axis seems to be alright but the labels won't show..